Unable to mock a function in pytest
I have the follow snipping code and I am trying to mock the utils.generic.generic_util.get_all_users but wen I run the rest return the value as is was called from the original function:
Pytest:
def test_get_all_request(user_valid_data, valid_request_response, mocker_encoded_jwt, mocker):
    response_model = models_user.UserInDB(**user_valid_data)

    mocker.patch.object(UserClient,
                        "get_current_user",
                        autospec=True,
                        return_value=response_model
                        )
    mocker.patch.object(UserClient,
                        "get_user",
                        autospec=True,
                        return_value=response_model
                        )
    mocker.patch("utils.generic.generic_util.get_all_users", autospec=True,
                 return_value=True)
  
    headers = {
        constants.MED_GROUPS_HEADER: f'{constants.ADMIN_GROUP}',
        constants.USER_HEADER: 'test@leo.com',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {mocker_encoded_jwt}'
    }
    response = client.get(f'/request', headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    print("especias ", response.json())
    assert response.json()[0]['attachment_path'] == valid_request_response[0]['attachment_path']

Endpoint:
@router.get("", status_code=200)
async def get_request_by(request_status: Optional[str] = None,
                         request_type: Optional[str] = None,
                         request_uuid: Optional[str] = None,
                         user_uuid: Optional[str] = None,
                         username: Optional[str] = None,
                         current_user: models_user.currentUser = Depends(User.get_current_user)):
    resp = {}
    if current_user and current_user.type == constants.SUPER_ADMIN:
        resp = await get_all_users(Request, Request._request_tablename, request_uuid=request_uuid, user_uuid=user_uuid, username=username, request_status=request_status, request_type=request_type)
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail=f'message: {current_user.username} not authorized.')
    return resp


patch where it is used, not where it’s defined
